# How do I set the margin of an object in IE?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to set the margin of an object from JavaScript. I am able to do it in Opera & Firefox, but the code doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

Here is the JavaScript I have:

```js
function SetTopMargin (ObjectID, Value)
{
    document.getElementById(ObjectID).style.marginTop =  Value.toString() + "px";
}
```

And it is called like this:

```js
SetTopMargin("test_div_id", 100);
```

So does anyone know some code that will work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: I just tried your code in IE7 and it worked fine...

Comment: Weird, I just tried the sample provided at the bottom which uses my code and it works....very confused :s

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Updated in 2016] On all current browsers (including IE8+), your code

```
document.getElementById(ObjectId).style.marginTop = Value.ToString() + 'px';
```

works fine.

On *very old* IE (< 8) versions, you must use this non-standard contraption instead:

```
document.getElementById(ObjectId).style.setAttribute(
   'marginTop', Value.ToString() + 'px');
```

**EDIT** - From deleted comment by OP:

> Note that while you can use style.setAttribute('margin-top', ..) in current IEs, 8 and older require style.setAttribute('marginTop', ..)

Answer (score 4):

Your code works in IE8 for me.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function SetTopMargin (ObjectID, Value)
    {   
      document.getElementById(ObjectID).style.marginTop =  Value.toString() + "px";
    }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <button id="btnTest" onclick="SetTopMargin('btnTest', 100);">Test</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

In IE6, it appears to be working as well after a very short pause.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, you should really use a javascript library like jQuery or Dojo. I also recommend www.debugbar.com for inspecting IE's DOM.

About your problem, `elem.style = "margin: 10px"` should work in IE.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Reason I am not using a library is that its bespoke. Built to be small and for a specific job. I am creating my own lightweight version of lightbox