# Why doesn't my intuitive declaration work?

Tags: javascript

```
var get = document.getElementById("t3");
get.style.visibility="visible";

var get = document.getElementById("answerbutton");
get.style="visibility:hidden";

var get = document.getElementById("spacer");
get.style="margin-top:160px";

var get = document.getElementById("spacer");
get.style.margin-top="160px";
```

I’m fairly new to JavaScript so excuse my naivety. The top three declarations work but if I use the forth one ( as I did originally ) it doesn’t. So, while I now know how to get the margin-top to change on the click of a button can someone please enlighten me as to what is wrong with the forth one.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`get.style.margin-top` is an arithmetic expression which cannot be the left-hand-side of an assignment.  It's like saying `(x - y) = z` which might work in Prolog but not in JavaScript, and is not what you want to do in any event.

Try

```
get.style.marginTop = ...
```

instead per [How do I set the margin of an object with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318158/how-do-i-set-the-margin-of-an-object-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a hyphen in an identifier (since it becomes a subtraction operator).

Property names when using dot-notation are identifiers.

The mapping of JavaScript properties and CSS properties is to use camelCase instead of hyphenation.

So: `marginTop` not `margin-top`.