# Margin when in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, html5-fullscreen

Starting fullscreen with Chrome by using `onInputDown` event for Text objects in Phaser enables fullscreen with margin on all sides. I found in Phaser examples that the same thing is happening with onDown event for `game.input`. http://phaser.io/examples/v2/display/fullscreen

I suspected my computer might be at fault but after asking a friend to try the example above he experienced something similar. The only difference was the background created by the margins.

Oddly enough if I were to call the same function that the `onInputDown` event from the Text object was calling but from a Button object instead there will be no margins. A proper fullscreen. Calling said function from an event listener added to html tags `<p>`, `<label>` and `<button>` etc. also works properly.

**My question is:** Why are margins created when enabling fullscreen in the way I explained in my first paragraph? Is there a way to remove those margins except for calling the function from a different source? If you get a proper fulllscreen from the example link using Chrome please add that in your answer.

```
//My fullscreen function
function ToggleFullScreen()
{
    var elem = document.documentElement;
    //Check if document is already in full screen or not.
    if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement)
    {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
          document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }       //If document is not already in full screen: Check if the document has the ability to go fullscreen.
    else if(document.fullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled ||document.msFullscreenEnabled)
    {
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    }//If the document can not go full screen: Alert the user.
    else
        window.alert("Sorry. Your device or brower does not support full screen.");
}
```

Comment: Have to tried, with javascript, to set margin on the tags to 0 just to see if it could do the trick ? So other reason i can think of is that some time, line breaks in your html code can cause an unwanted margin, have you tried to minify your HTML into a single line ? This could be the reason why you got those margins

Comment: I am not sure if I followed your suggestion correctly. When setting margin with javascript I typed as this questions answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318158/how-do-i-set-the-margin-of-an-object-with-javascript and I compressed everything except my script to a single line and that did not help either.

An important note would be that I do not get any white borders/margin when I request fullscreen with the window minimized. A bug maybe?